# Why a box shadow is getting cut and hidden by a figure element underneath?

Tags: html, css

I have recurring ui schema on the page i build at the moment. Sections in a certain background color, an aside element with a logo and a random quote and an image inside a figure element underneath. The rough outline is:

```
<section>
    <aside></aside>
    <figure></figure>
</section>
```

The aside is styled with :

```
aside {
    background-color:white;
    text-align:center;
    @include box-shadow(black .1em .1em 1em);
    padding:1em 0;
}
```

The section basically with:

```
section {
    background-color: #AB6056;
}
```

Nothing really spectacular. But the box shadow underneath the aside gets cut of by the figure element.

[image: box shadow gets cut by image]

if i comment out the figure element the box shadow is shown.

[image: the box shadow is shown]

What is the reason causing that behaviour and is there a way to prevent that behaviour? Best regards Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be caused by positioning and/or z-indexing.

In your case, setting the aside's position to relative should do the trick:

```
aside {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: If this is not the case, would you mind recreating the page in jsfiddle?

Comment: No unfortunately that isn't working. And sure i will build it in Codepen. Hoped by the outline it might be a known problem so i delayed the pen or fiddle first. But sure no prob

Comment: No worries, it's good enough. Anyway, my solution works fine for me. Is this what you wanted? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nwfGz

Comment: Coooool! Now it's working for me too - in the pen as well as in my project page (Before i set up the pen it hasn't in my project). Thanks a lot! But may i ask why it solves the issue to apply a position: relative to the element with the box shadow? Not a solution i would have expected in the first place. ;)

Comment: You're welcome! :) I can't give you tech details from the top of my head, but I'll give you a nice tutorial where everything is described: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101  Basically, think of it like this: relatively positioned elements have a "higher priority/importance" than those with no position defined.

Comment: Just fyi, the reason the `figure` renders on top of the `aside` is because it comes after in the source code. Unless you apply positioning (apparently with or without `z-index`) elements are stacked on top of each other in source order.

Comment: @Shomz Basically i already know that article, but i guess i will reread it and dig a bit further. Thanks again!

Comment: @rpk yea in order for z-index to have any effect the element needs to be "positioned" (ie have a `position` other than `static`)